# フィールドセット内に設置した要素の値の一括取得において、この要素特有で推奨されるような方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, html

フィールドセット内に複数のフォーム入力要素を設置して、それらの要素の値を一括で取得したいとしましょう。このときに**推奨されるような**方法として、**フィールドセット要素にのみ使うような**属性やWeb APIはあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[elements プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement#htmlfieldsetelement.elements)でループして値を取得すればよいでしょう。

Comment: まさにそのインターフェイスの特にそのプロパティをが思い浮かべながら質問していましたが、それで実際にどのように値を取得していますか？そしてなぜ推奨されると言えますか？普段はDocumentを使って取得しています。

Comment: このプロパティを使った取得は可能です。[リンクされたスペシフィケーション](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmlfieldsetelement)を見てDocumentよりも適切なケースはありそうだと思いましたが、常にではありません。そしてMDNのこのプロパティの説明はよくわかりません。だからこのプロパティには確信が持てません。だからこのプロパティの提案では、どんなケースをどんな理由で適切だと考えているのかを同時に知りたいと思っています。